# WPF iterate through items in a listview

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a `ListView` with a `CheckBox` as one of the columns, bound to a boolean property of a custom object.  I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through the items in the `ListView` and check all the checkboxes.  What I have so far is below:

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="275" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Enabled">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub SelectAll_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles SelectAll.Click
    Dim currSelected As Integer = MyListView.SelectedIndex
    MyListView.SelectAll()
    For ixItem As Integer = 0 To MyListView.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        coItems(ixItem).IsChecked = True
    Next
    MyListView.SelectedIndex = currSelected
End Sub
```

I have a hunch this is actually pretty easy, and I'm just missing one line somewhere.  Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE:** The problem more specifically is that the checkboxes that are visible when the button is pressed aren't being displayed as checked, but the ones that aren't visible (because the user needs to scroll down to see them) are displayed as checked.

**UPDATE 2:** As requested, here is the PropertyChanged code.  I'm still fairly new to WPF, I haven't done much with INotifyPropertyChanged before.

```
Public Property blnIsChecked() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _blnIsChecked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _blnIsChecked = value
        End Set
    End Property

Public Event PropertyChangedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

Comment: If you trigger the CheckAll event, then get your program to redraw the screen (such as minimizing the program and re-opening it), do the items show up as checked?

Comment: Yes, actually.  There are items that are below the fold, and those ones do appear checked.  (ie: Checkboxes that aren't visible when the button is pressed are checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the items in the listview without using SelectedItems, just use ListView.Items.  that way you don't have to change the selection.

Is your underlying model not properly firing property change notifications?  if not, you're setting IsChecked on them, but they aren't telling the listview.

What *specificly* isn't working?

Comment: that would imply to me that your property change notifications aren't firing properly on your custom object.  if your list is "virtualized", the ones "below the fold" don't really exist until you scroll, so when they get created, they get the "correct" value.  i'd make sure that your custom object is correctly doing property change notifications on its IsChecked property.  Can you post/update some of that in the question?